# @RequestMapping with body implementation in superclass

Tags: java, spring

I have some entities and a separate controller for each of them. In these controllers, there is one method that is always the same and it is the edit form route. I have a service that builds a form for any given entity so basically this method has three lines: build the form, assign to the model, return the view name. The view is also the same as the only difference on that page is the form. So what is different is the path and the path variable's type (Entity type).

I would like to move this one method to a common superclass. I could solve the type of the path variable with some generic types. The problem is the path. I know that the value of `@RequestMapping` has to be a constant so is there any other way around it?

I guess I could technically create a method that does what I need then in every inherited class I can create another method that calls this one or even overrides the original method. I was just curious if there was a better way.

Comment: Have you tried putting `@RequestMapping("/{id}/edit")` on the method and `@RequestMapping("/widgets")` on the subclass?

Comment: Oh, I did not think of this :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're describing: 'creating a method that does what you need in the super class' then assigning the @RequestMapping in the concrete implementation to create the routing, is likely the common best practice for handling this in Spring.

If you want to be fancy with the Spring route mapping you can manipulate them at start up using the `RequestMappingHandler` to manually assign route mappings to a controller method, but note that `@RequestMapping` on a class will create a route for the method even if it's an abstract class (not sure about on abstract methods, but I assume not). However you can use `@RequestMapping` on interfaces abstractly. You can find an example of how to do that [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handler-adapters#4-requestmappinghandleradapter)

Using the above handler you could create your own type of inheritance chain using reflections and a custom annotation on the base class that you manually assign to the route base in the request mapping handler.